# Multiselect in Listbox

Tags: jquery

I am working on a Banner Workflow. Currently the banner does not have a multiselect listbox. I want the users to have a multiselect option. I am trying to write jQuery code so I can make my listbox in to a multiselect. Somehow the multiselect does not work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#dataField369").multiselect();
  });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dataField369").change(function() {
      var myvalueMultiple = jQuery(this).val();
      alert("You have selected : " + myvalueMultiple);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide your `#dataField369` HTML. Also, did you check if you have any JS errors in the console?

Comment: can you create an example where we can see the error ourselves?

Comment: why jquery.min.js added 2 times?

Comment: What multiselect library are you using?

Comment: #dataField369  is the control on the form I am not writing a HTML for generating the list box. I can not see the errors as I am using banner workflow